# Having trouble with pythons sub function using regex

Tags: python, regex

Basically Im trying to get a string between two characters to change to another string no matter what characters are between the two characters.

Heres an example of what I've tried:

```
test_string = 'This:<123Hello$%^> <890World!@#>'

new_string = re.sub('<(.*)>', 'It Worked!!', test_string)

print(new_string)
```

Output should be: `'This:<It Worked!!> <It Worked!!>'`
but Im only getting It Worked!! please help thanks.

Comment: `.*` greedily matches from the first `<` to the last `>`. You want an ungreedy match `.*?`, or be more specific than `.`: `<([^>]*)>`.

Comment: And you need `re.findall` to *extract* matches. `re.sub` replaces them.